# problema en retorno despues q se envia el formulario ajax + express

Tags: ajax, nodejs, express

tengo un problema con mi app

cuando el usuario envia el formulario mediante un ajax para que la pagina no recargue, me lo envia perfecto pero la pagina se me pone en blanco y me dice cargado por mi res.send(), no veo la forma de decirle a mi codigo ajax que reciba la repuesta.

mi front-end:

```
...
    script>
    jQuery('#uploader').on('submit',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();   
    var form = $('#uploader')[0];
    var formData = new FormData(form);

    

    jQuery.ajax({
      url: '/mostrador/asig_data/{{id}}',
      data: formData,
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
    }).done( response => {
        console.log(response)
    })
});
...
```

mi nodejs - express dice:

```
} catch (error) {
    res.redirect('/mostrador/data_mostrador/' + id_item);
    req.flash('danger', 'Ingreso un dato mal: '+ error_flash);
}

res.send('cargado');
```

agradezco la manito y gracias son los mejores

Comment: Cual es la estructura de tu formulario?

Answer (score 0):

lo logre, mi formulario se enviaba con un onblur asi:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nota_entrega" value="{{nota_entrega}}" onblur="mySubmit(this.form)">
```

entonces mi script quedo de la siguiente manera en el front-end

```
    <script>
   function mySubmit(theForm) {
    $.ajax({ 
        data: $(theForm).serialize(), 
        type: $(theForm).attr('method'), 
        url: $(theForm).attr('action'), 
        success: function (response) { 
            console.log(response); 
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

y en mi router de express quedo asi despues de guardar los datos

```
res.send('Informacion Guardada')
```

todo funciono a la perfeccion